# How sort double vector according to changes in first vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I would like to implement something like DoubleVector.
In this class I would also like to implement sort method, which sort v1_ and according to changes in v1_ the order in v2_ will also change.
The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class DoubleVector
{
    vector<int> v1_;
    vector<char> v2_;
public:
    void sort()
    {
        //sort v1_ and also change order in v2_ according to changes in v1_
        std::sort(v1_.begin(), v1_.end() /*, lambda ?*/);
    }
    void add(int value_v1, char value_v2)
    {
        v1_.push_back(value_v1);
        v2_.push_back(value_v2);
    }
    void print()
    {
        const auto size = v1_.size();
        for (size_t i=0;i<size;++i)
        {
            cout << v1_[i] << " " << v2_[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    DoubleVector dv;
    dv.add(6, 'g');
    dv.add(2, 'r');
    dv.add(3, 'y');
    dv.add(4, 'a');
    cout << "Before sort:" << endl;
    dv.print();
    dv.sort();
    cout << "After sort:" << endl;
    dv.print();//the values in v2_ are in the same order they don't change order according to v1_ changes
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see DoubleVector before sort contains:

```
6 g
2 r
3 y
4 a
```

And after sort contains:

```
2 g
3 r
4 y
6 a
```

I would like to get:

```
2 r
3 y
4 a
6 g
```

So the first vector v1_ has been sorted, but the second still has got the same order and I would like to change order of elements in second v2_ vector according to changes in v1_.
I can write it, but I would like to do it in a fast and clean way, maybe using lambda as third argument in std::sort function? Vectors v1_ and v2_ in class DoubleVector must stay as they are.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `which sort v1_ and according to changes in v1_ the order in v2_ will also change.` `Vectors v1_ and v2_ in class DoubleVector must stay as they are.` I am confused, do you want the sort to modify v1_ and v2_ or do you want it to return a new DoubleVector?

Answer (score 3):

Make a vector of `std::pair<int,char>` instead. Since `operator <` on the pair compares `first` and decides ties on the `second`, sorting `std::vector<std::pair<int,char>>` will produce the exact effect that you want:

```
vector<pair<int,char>> v;
v.push_back(make_pair(6, 'g'));
v.push_back(make_pair(2, 'r'));
v.push_back(make_pair(3, 'y'));
v.push_back(make_pair(4, 'a'));
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
for (int i = 0 ; i != v.size() ; i++) {
    cout << v[i].first << " " << v[i].second << endl;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Bl4Sp4)

Comment: Thank you, but vectors v1_ and v2_ in class DoubleVector must stay as they are.

Comment: @user2856064 copy them into a vector of pairs, sort, and copy back.

Comment: That costs a lot. Maybe there is better solution.

Comment: @user2856064 how do you know how much it costs until you profile it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:-

```
vector< pair<int,char> >v;
//do what you want
sort(v.begin(),v.end())
```

The sort function by default sorts according to first value but you can always define according to which criteria should the sort work

- [C++ STL - How does the third argument of the STL sort() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887963/c-stl-how-does-the-third-argument-of-the-stl-sort-work)

Comment: Thank you, but vectors v1_ and v2_ in class DoubleVector must stay as they are.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723066/c-stl-custom-sorting-one-vector-based-on-contents-of-another This might help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

The way it works is to sort the position key pair based on the int vector value only and then use this ordering to extract values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class dv
{
  std::vector<int> _v1;
  std::vector<char> _v2;
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > _order;

public:
  inline bool operator() (const std::pair<int, int>& v1_index_1, 
                          const std::pair<int, int>& v1_index_2) const {
    return _v1[v1_index_1.first] < _v1[v1_index_2.first]; 
  }

  void sort() {
    std::sort(_order.begin(), _order.end(), *this);
  }

  void add(int value_v1, char value_v2) {
    _order.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(_v1.size(), _v2.size()));
    _v1.push_back(value_v1);
    _v2.push_back(value_v2);
  }

  void print() {
    const auto size(_v1.size());
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) {      
      std::cout << _v1[_order[i].first] 
                << " " 
                << _v2[_order[i].second] 
                << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

int main() {

  dv dv;

  dv.add(6, 'g');
  dv.add(2, 'r');
  dv.add(3, 'y');
  dv.add(4, 'a');

  std::cout << "before sort: " << std::endl;

  dv.print();

  std::cout << "sorting: " << std::endl;

  dv.sort();

  std::cout << "after sort: " << std::endl;

  dv.print();

  return 0;
}
```