# How do I sort a vector of pairs based on both first and second element in a pair?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

if i have a vector of pairs
 `vector<pair<int, int>> arr;`
and passes elements like

```
4 5
3 7
10 5
5 7
1 5
```

how can i make the pair to sort the elements depend on the first and second element in a pair like this in descending order

```
5 7
3 7
10 5
4 5
1 5
```

or in ascending order

```
1 5
4 5 
10 5
3 7
5 7
```

Edit: what i want sort the vector depend on both sides for example
second element ***5*** repeated 3 times with first elements (4, 10, 1) and second element ***7*** repeated 2 times with first elements (3, 5)

so if i sort them in descending order the repeated ***7*** will come first then ***5*** it will be like that

```
3 7
5 7
4 5
10 5
1 5
```

then sort the first elements with ***7*** also in descending order to become (5, 3) then first elements with ***5*** to become (10, 4, 1)
so the final array will be like that

```
5 7
3 7
10 5
4 5
1 5
```

Comment: Have you tried the 3 argument version of [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?  If you did, please post your attempt and what issues you are having.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888039/13742330) is how to pass the third argument. It is either a function pointer or a lambda function.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean “sort by the second element, and if those are equal, then sort by the first element”?

Comment: @JonPurdy yes, this is what i mean

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply use the std::sort to sort it in ascending order

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arr;
arr.push_back({ 4, 5 });
arr.push_back({ 3, 7 });
arr.push_back({ 10, 5 });
arr.push_back({ 5, 7 });
arr.push_back({ 1, 5 });
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

In addition you can sort in descending order using std::greater<>()

```
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::greater<>());
```

After Edit: If your question is to sort by second element than if the second element are equal to sort by the first element than this might a solution

(it in ascending order)

```
bool sortBySecondElement(const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int> & p2)
{
    return p1.second < p2.second;
}

bool sortByFirstElement(const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2)
{
    return p1.second == p2.second && p1.first < p2.first;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arr;
    arr.push_back({ 4, 5 });
    arr.push_back({ 3, 7 });
    arr.push_back({ 10, 5 });
    arr.push_back({ 5, 7 });
    arr.push_back({ 1, 5 });
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), sortBySecondElement);
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), sortByFirstElement);
}
```

Comment: Both of the comparators here are incorrect, though close.

Comment: The easy way to do this is `return std::tie(p1.second, p1.first) < std::tie(p2.second, p2.first);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and apply the proper sort criteria:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

bool SortAscending(const std::pair<int,int>& p1, const std::pair<int,int>& p2)
{
   return std::tie(p1.second, p1.first) < std::tie(p2.second, p2.first);
}

bool SortDescending(const std::pair<int,int>& p1, const std::pair<int,int>& p2)
{
   return std::tie(p1.second, p1.first) > std::tie(p2.second, p2.first);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arr = 
              {{4, 5},{3, 7}, {10, 5}, {5, 7},{1, 5}};

    std::cout << "Original: \n";
    for (auto& p : arr)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";

    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), SortAscending);
    std::cout << "\n\nAscending: \n";
    for (auto& p : arr)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";

    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), SortDescending);
    std::cout << "\n\nDescending: \n";
    for (auto& p : arr)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Original: 
4 5
3 7
10 5
5 7
1 5


Ascending: 
1 5
4 5
10 5
3 7
5 7


Descending: 
5 7
3 7
10 5
4 5
1 5
```